# flutter sharedpreferences not setting state from first built

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to have values saved in sharedPreferences loaded when the app loads. But it gives me always the static list of double declared [0,0,0,0,0,0] at first built. whenever i touch something that set the state it changes to my correct values. I don't even need that static list I am just declaring it because dart is asking me. I want the default list if there is nothing already saved in there, otherwise I want the sharedpreferences saved list. here is my code.

```
@override initState()  {
    super.initState();
    callLoad();
  }

  callLoad() async{
    List<double> list = await loadTimers();
    setState((){
      timersList = list;
    });
  }

  Future<List<double>> loadTimers() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList =  prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    List<double> defaultTimersList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];
    List<double> savedTimerList;
      if (myList == null ){
        return defaultTimersList;
      } else{
        savedTimerList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
        return savedTimerList;
      }
  }

  static List<double> timersList = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

  double timeRemaining1 = timersList[0];
  double timeRemaining2 = timersList[1];
  double timeRemaining3 = timersList[2];
  double timeRemaining4 = timersList[3];
  double timeRemaining5 = timersList[4];
  double timeRemaining6 = timersList[5];
```

I tried this way too but it is the same.

```
@override initState()  {
    super.initState();
    loadTimers();
  }


  loadTimers() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList =  prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    List<double> defaultTimersList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];
    List<double> savedTimerList;
      if (myList == null ){
        setState(() {
          timersList = defaultTimersList;

        });
      } else{
        savedTimerList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
         setState(() {
           timersList = savedTimerList;
         });
      }
  }

  static List<double> timersList = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

  double timeRemaining1 = timersList[0];
  double timeRemaining2 = timersList[1];
  double timeRemaining3 = timersList[2];
  double timeRemaining4 = timersList[3];
  double timeRemaining5 = timersList[4];
  double timeRemaining6 = timersList[5];
```

Thank you

Edit with little app showing the problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo chokuns page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override initState()  {
    super.initState();
    callLoad();
  }

  callLoad() async{
    List<double> list = await loadTimers();
    setState((){
      timersList = list;
    });
  }

  Future<List<double>> loadTimers() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> myList =  prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    List<double> defaultTimersList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];
    List<double> savedTimerList;
    if (myList == null ){
      return defaultTimersList;
    } else{
      savedTimerList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
      return savedTimerList;
    }
  }

  static List<double> timersList = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

  double timeRemaining1 = timersList[0];
  double timeRemaining2 = timersList[1];
  double timeRemaining3 = timersList[2];
  double timeRemaining4 = timersList[3];
  double timeRemaining5 = timersList[4];
  double timeRemaining6 = timersList[5];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button \nthis many times:',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Text(
              '$timeRemaining1', //showing here $timersList it shows correct values
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In my case, It works well. How is build part?

Comment: yes it works but the first build it uses the values declared in static list<double> timersList, and not those in the sharedpreferences. I think that it first draw screen and after it sets the value because after any kind of setstate after it launches it updates correctly.

Comment: I edited the question. now you can check it better with this little example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `callLoad` to:

```
  callLoad() async{
    List<double> list = await loadTimers();
    setState((){
      timersList = list;
      timeRemaining1 = timersList[0];
      timeRemaining2 = timersList[1];
      timeRemaining3 = timersList[2];
      timeRemaining4 = timersList[3];
      timeRemaining5 = timersList[4];
      timeRemaining6 = timersList[5];
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yes obviously I can initialize them calling function from the initState too. I feel dumb. thank you really much richard for all your help. I understood a lot of things however trying to fixing this up.

Comment: I think OP wants to know the why. It was question.

Comment: Well, actually, no, you can't do it in `initState` as the future hasn't completed. What you have done by defining the 6 local variables is to create a whole load more state in `MyHomePageState`. The problem is that your `callLoad` function only updated some of that state (`timersList`) but neglected to update the rest of the state (`timeRemaining*`). As @yahocho points out, the six variables duplicate what you are already storing in the list, but it's been obvious from your earlier questions that you need/want these for some reason. This is why I left them and showed what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Dart is passing by reference of object.
So, Your idea is correct. But, I will explain why it does not work.
It is caused by `List<double> list = await loadTimers();` because it is new object.
Below code shows `TrueTrue`.
But, If you change `//isSameList = identical(timersList, timersList2);` to `isSameList = identical(timersList, timersList2);`, It shows `FalseTrue`. You have to restart it.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  SharedPreferences prefs;
  static List<double> timersList = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
  double timeRemaining1;
  List<double> timersList2;
  bool isSameList;
  bool isSameValue;

  @override initState()  {
    super.initState();
    initValues();
    callLoad();
  }

  void initValues()
  {
    timeRemaining1 = timersList[0];
    timersList2 = timersList;
    isSameList = identical(timersList, timersList2);
    isSameValue = identical(timersList[0], timeRemaining1);
  }

  Future<void> callLoad() async{
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<double> list = await loadTimers();
    setState((){
      timersList = list;
      //isSameList = identical(timersList, timersList2);
    });
  }

  List<double> loadTimers() {
    List<String> myList =  prefs.getStringList('TimerList');
    List<double> defaultTimersList = [30.0, 60.0, 90.0, 120.0, 150.0, 180.0];
    List<double> savedTimerList;
    if (myList == null ){
      return defaultTimersList;
    } else{
      savedTimerList = myList.map((i)=> double.parse(i)).toList();
      return savedTimerList;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button \nthis many times:',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            Text(
              '$isSameList'+'$isSameValue', //showing here $timersList it shows correct values
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Finally, I could know how to use `pass by reference` for the list.

```
timersList.setAll(0, list);
```

It shows the result well. But, `timeRemaining1` still can not be showed becuase it can not keep the `reference`. So, I think you can handle it with List object as above way.

Comment: Does it displays the sharedPreferences values even if you close and then re-launch the app? To me it shows all zeros and only after I touch something it renders all the correct values. I would like to have those values from the first build too.

Comment: you should try to display in the widget Text not the timersList but the indexes of that: timersList[0]

Comment: I edited my question with your code modified by only using in that widget the value of remainingTimerValue1, and it loads me with 0.0. Check it out please. Thank you

Comment: @FlorisMarpepa I updated the answer. You are right. I just found out it is caused by new instance.